# Wordpress: How to get posts that don't contain a specific category with a custom query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to display all posts that don't contain a specific category.
I use the following query, but I retrive also the post that contains the category 81 since this post contains also other categories.
Is there a way to sort it out?

```
SELECT p1.*, wm2.meta_value 
FROM wp_posts p1 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wm1 ON (
    wm1.post_id = p1.id
    AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
    AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
)
LEFT JOIN
wp_postmeta wm2
ON (
    wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
    AND wm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
    AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL
)
LEFT JOIN
wp_term_relationships wtr
ON (
    object_id=p1.id
)
WHERE
p1.post_status='publish'
AND p1.post_type='post'
AND `term_taxonomy_id`<>81
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY p1.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using bare SQL rather than the `WP_Query()` class?

Comment: Yes. I have to use wordpress only as a backoffice to load content. All the frontend in custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works

```
SELECT p1.*, wm2.meta_value 
FROM wp_posts p1 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wm1 ON (
    wm1.post_id = p1.id
    AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
    AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
)
LEFT JOIN
wp_postmeta wm2
ON (
    wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
    AND wm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
    AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL
)
LEFT JOIN
wp_term_relationships wtr
ON (
    object_id=p1.id
)
WHERE
p1.post_status='publish'
AND p1.post_type='post'
AND object_id NOT IN (SELECT `object_id` FROM wp_term_relationships where `term_taxonomy_id`=81)
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY p1.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```